# Linq sorting List<string> and write only with some char

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

my question is : Im making program where user input any words he want until he write END.

All words goes to same List string

and from that list I need to write:

1) words that starts with "A"

2) words that starts with "B"

3) words that starts with "C"

4) other words:

Maybe using linq

If anyone have some not so complicated solution for beginner I would be really thankfull.
I tried to find other answers without success.

Comment: Hi Matej. Have you tried to write some code lines? Did you got anything or any error?

Comment: Hi Matej, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have a list of all the words, such as `var words = new List<string>();`, and you filled this with all the words the user inputted, then to find words that starts with an A, you could do: `var aWords = words.Where(w => w.ToUpper().StartsWith("A")).ToList();`. This should give you a starting point for the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate pattern and then group matches by first letter.

```
// Generate pattern: A|B|C
var check_words = string.Join("|", "A", "B", "C");
var re = new Regex($"^{check_words}");
// Test strings
var words = new List<string> { "Apple", "Banana", "Cucumber", "Cherry", "Watermelon" };
var filtered =
    words
    .Where(word => re.IsMatch(word)) //Filter words
    .GroupBy(g => g.Substring(0, 1)); //Group by first letter

// Print groups
foreach(var group in filtered)
{
    WriteLine($"Group: {group.Key}");
    foreach(var x in group)
    {
        WriteLine($"\t{x}");
    }
}

/*
Output:

Group: A
        Apple
Group: B
        Banana
Group: C
        Cucumber
        Cherry
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

var words=List();
 var aWords = words.Where(w => w.ToUpper().StartsWith("A")).ToList();

this works for me thanks  @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen

Can you just help me how I can say i want all other words that dont starts with A, B or C
to be written together via linq?